# 4 substrings from String

Tags: java, android, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have the following string:

```
"Sample text, another sample","勾","","勾"
```

I want to get 4 substrings as follows:

- Sample text, another sample
- 勾
- //just empty string
- 勾

Can someone post solution on how to achieve that? If possible, could you show me two ways to do that (standard way and by using regular expressions). Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll want to do a regex search for all strings that are within quotes. All matches for the pattern `"[^"]*"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = "\"Sample text, another sample\",\"勾\",\"\",\"勾\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subString(int start, int end)` method

for example:

```
str.subString(0,5);
```

will give you Sample